# How do you remove sections from a csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file

I am following along with this project guide and I reached a segment where I'm not exactly sure how the code works. Can someone explain the following block of code please:

```
to_drop = ['Edition Statement',
       'Corporate Author',
       'Corporate Contributors',
       'Former owner',
       'Engraver',
       'Contributors',
       'Issuance type',
       'Shelfmarks']

df.drop(to_drop, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

This is the format of the csv file before the previous code is executed:

```
    Identifier             Edition Statement      Place of Publication  \
0         206                           NaN                    London
1         216                           NaN  London; Virtue & Yorston
2         218                           NaN                    London
3         472                           NaN                    London
4         480  A new edition, revised, etc.                    London

  Date of Publication              Publisher  \
0         1879 [1878]       S. Tinsley & Co.
1                1868           Virtue & Co.
2                1869  Bradbury, Evans & Co.
3                1851          James Darling
4                1857   Wertheim & Macintosh

                                           Title     Author  \
0                  Walter Forbes. [A novel.] By A. A      A. A.
1  All for Greed. [A novel. The dedication signed...  A., A. A.
2  Love the Avenger. By the author of “All for Gr...  A., A. A.
3  Welsh Sketches, chiefly ecclesiastical, to the...  A., E. S.
4  [The World in which I live, and my place in it...  A., E. S.

                               Contributors  Corporate Author  \
0                               FORBES, Walter.               NaN
1  BLAZE DE BURY, Marie Pauline Rose - Baroness               NaN
2  BLAZE DE BURY, Marie Pauline Rose - Baroness               NaN
3                   Appleyard, Ernest Silvanus.               NaN
4                           BROOME, John Henry.               NaN

   Corporate Contributors Former owner  Engraver Issuance type  \
0                     NaN          NaN       NaN   monographic
1                     NaN          NaN       NaN   monographic
2                     NaN          NaN       NaN   monographic
3                     NaN          NaN       NaN   monographic
4                     NaN          NaN       NaN   monographic

                                      Flickr URL  \
0  http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/ta...
1  http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/ta...
2  http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/ta...
3  http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/ta...
4  http://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/ta...

                        Shelfmarks
0    British Library HMNTS 12641.b.30.
1    British Library HMNTS 12626.cc.2.
2    British Library HMNTS 12625.dd.1.
3    British Library HMNTS 10369.bbb.15.
4    British Library HMNTS 9007.d.28.
```

Which part of the code tells pandas to remove the columns and not rows? What does the inplace=True and axis=1 mean?

Comment: axis =1 indicates the columnwise drop, axis=0 for rows. inplace means that the new dataframe is assigned to the same variable name. when you you print df, you can see the changes.

Comment: inplace means that the manipulation done to the df let's say will be made directly to the variable that's holding it; it doesn't needs to be re-assigned, axis is deciding whether you are dropping rows or enitre columns;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really basic in Pandas data frame, I guess you should take on a free tutorial.Anyways this code block removes the columns that you have stored in to_drop.
So far a data frame whose name is df we remove columns using this command

```
df.drop([], inplace=True), axis=1,
```

where in list we mention the columns we want to drop, axis =1 means to drop them columnwise and in place simply makes it a permanent change that this change will occur actually on the original dataframe.

You can also write the above command as

```
df.drop(['Edition Statement',
   'Corporate Author',
   'Corporate Contributors',
   'Former owner',
   'Engraver',
   'Contributors',
   'Issuance type',
   'Shelfmarks'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Here is quite basic guide to pandas for your future queries [Introduction to pandas](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/python-pandas-tutorial/)